# Using StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscription with Java AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

How to send `ConfigurationEvent` to `StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionRequest`? I've configured following request but I'm unable to figure out how to send `ConfigurationEvent` object to body of this request.

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputFile);
int channelId = 0;
ParticipantRole participantRole = ParticipantRole.AGENT;
ChannelDefinition channelDefinition = ChannelDefinition.builder()
                .channelId(channelId)
                .participantRole(participantRole)
                .build();
ConfigurationEvent configurationEvent = ConfigurationEvent.builder()
                .channelDefinitions(channelDefinition)
                .build();
        AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
                .mediaSampleRateHertz(8000)
                .enablePartialResultsStabilization(true)
                .partialResultsStability("high")
                .languageCode(CallAnalyticsLanguageCode.EN_US)
                .mediaEncoding(getAwsMediaEncoding(audioFormat))
            .overrideConfiguration(AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .putExecutionAttribute(new ExecutionAttribute<>("ConfigurationEvent"), configurationEvent).build())
                .build();
```

Whenever I'm invoking it, I'm getting following exception:

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.transcribestreaming.model.BadRequestException: You must provide ConfigurationEvent as the first event in the stream (Service: transcribe, Status Code: 400, Request ID: e66c528c-55ae-4bf4-a0da-aa2d389ec1cf)
```

Here's complete code:

```
private static StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler getAnalyticsResponseHandler(String file) {
        return StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionResponseHandler.builder()
                .onError(e-> {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                    System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + sw);
                })
                .onComplete(() -> System.out.println("====Analytics Completed.===="))
                .onResponse(res -> System.out.println("contentRedactionTypeAsString----" + res.contentRedactionTypeAsString()))
                .onEventStream(event -> {
                    event.doAfterOnError(e -> {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
                        System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + sw);
                    });
                    event.doAfterOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("====Analytics Completed.===="));
                    var eventType = event.map(CallAnalyticsTranscriptResultStream::sdkEventType);
                    event.subscribe(c -> System.out.println(c.sdkEventType()));
                    System.out.println("EventType:" + eventType);
                    //var analyticsSettings = ((ConfigurationEvent)event).postCallAnalyticsSettings();
                    System.out.println("------UtteranceEvent------");
                    System.out.println();
                })
                .build();
    }

private static class CallAnalyticsAudioStreamPublisher implements Publisher<AudioStream> {
        private final ConfigurationEvent configurationEvent;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private static Subscription currentSubscription;
        private CallAnalyticsAudioStreamPublisher(String fileName, InputStream inputStream, ConfigurationEvent configurationEvent) {
            this.configurationEvent = configurationEvent;
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }
        @Override
        public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s) {
            if (currentSubscription == null) {
                currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            } else {
                currentSubscription.cancel();
                currentSubscription = new SubscriptionImpl(s, inputStream);
            }
            s.onSubscribe(currentSubscription);
        }
    }

    public static class SubscriptionImpl implements Subscription {
        private static final int CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 1024;
        private final Subscriber<? super AudioStream> subscriber;
        private final InputStream inputStream;
        private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        private final AtomicLong demand = new AtomicLong(0);

        SubscriptionImpl(Subscriber<? super AudioStream> s, InputStream inputStream) {
            this.subscriber = s;
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public void request(long n) {
            if (n <= 0) {
                subscriber.onError(new IllegalArgumentException("Demand must be positive"));
            }
            demand.getAndAdd(n);
            executor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    do {
                        ByteBuffer audioBuffer = getNextEvent();
                        if (audioBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                            AudioEvent audioEvent = audioEventFromBuffer(audioBuffer);
                            subscriber.onNext(audioEvent);
                        } else {
                            subscriber.onComplete();
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (demand.decrementAndGet() > 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        private ByteBuffer getNextEvent() throws IOException {
            ByteBuffer audioBuffer = null;
            byte[] audioBytes = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE_IN_BYTES];
            int len;
            try {
                len = inputStream.read(audioBytes);

                if (len <= 0) {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);
                } else {
                    audioBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(audioBytes, 0, len);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
            return audioBuffer;
        }

        private AudioEvent audioEventFromBuffer(ByteBuffer bb) {
            return AudioEvent.builder()
                    .audioChunk(SdkBytes.fromByteBuffer(bb))
                    .build();
        }
    }
private static MediaEncoding getAwsMediaEncoding(AudioFormat audioFormat) {
        final String javaMediaEncoding = audioFormat.getEncoding().toString();
        System.out.println("Java Media Encoding:" + javaMediaEncoding);
        if (PCM_SIGNED.toString().equals(javaMediaEncoding)) {
            return MediaEncoding.PCM;
        } else if (PCM_UNSIGNED.toString().equals(javaMediaEncoding)){
            return MediaEncoding.PCM;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a recognized media encoding:" + javaMediaEncoding);
    }

    private static Integer getAwsSampleRate(AudioFormat audioFormat) {
        return Math.round(audioFormat.getSampleRate());
    }
private static StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionRequest getAnalyticsRequest(File inputFile) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputFile);
        int channelId = 0;
        ParticipantRole participantRole = ParticipantRole.AGENT;
        if(inputFile.getName().contains("_R")) {
            channelId = 1;
            participantRole = ParticipantRole.CUSTOMER;
        }
        ChannelDefinition channelDefinition = ChannelDefinition.builder()
                .channelId(channelId)
                .participantRole(participantRole)
                .build();
        ConfigurationEvent configurationEvent = ConfigurationEvent.builder()
                .channelDefinitions(channelDefinition)
                .build();
        AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        return StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionRequest.builder()
                .mediaSampleRateHertz(8000)
                .enablePartialResultsStabilization(true)
                .partialResultsStability("high")
                .languageCode(CallAnalyticsLanguageCode.EN_US)
                .mediaEncoding(getAwsMediaEncoding(audioFormat))
                .overrideConfiguration(AwsRequestOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .putExecutionAttribute(new ExecutionAttribute<>("ConfigurationEvent"), configurationEvent).build())
                .build();
    }
private static InputStream getStreamFromFile(String file) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File(file);
            return new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static ConfigurationEvent getConfigurationEvent(String inputFile) {
        int channelId = 0;
        ParticipantRole participantRole = ParticipantRole.AGENT;
        if(inputFile.contains("_R")) {
            channelId = 1;
            participantRole = ParticipantRole.CUSTOMER;
        }
        ChannelDefinition channelDefinition = ChannelDefinition.builder()
                .channelId(channelId)
                .participantRole(participantRole)
                .build();
        return ConfigurationEvent.builder()
                .channelDefinitions(channelDefinition)
                .build();
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        var resources = Paths.get(...);
        var fileList = resources.toFile().listFiles();
        var wavFiles = Arrays.stream(fileList).filter(it -> it.getName().contains(".wav")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        AwsCredentialsProvider provider = EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create();
        NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder customHttp = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
                .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .writeTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .tcpKeepAlive(true);
        TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient client = TranscribeStreamingAsyncClient.builder()
                .region(REGION)
                .credentialsProvider(provider)
                .httpClientBuilder(customHttp)
                .build();
        wavFiles.forEach(f -> {
            try {
                String dest = f.getParentFile().getParentFile().getPath().concat("\\processed\\");
                String interimFile = dest.concat("\\interim\\").concat(f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().indexOf(".")).concat("-interim.txt"));
                String file = dest.concat(f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().indexOf(".")).concat(".txt"));
                System.out.println("###############################");
                var completableFuture = client.startCallAnalyticsStreamTranscription(getAnalyticsRequest(new File(f.toURI()))
                        , new CallAnalyticsAudioStreamPublisher(f.getName(), getStreamFromFile(String.valueOf(f)), getConfigurationEvent(f.getName())),
                        getAnalyticsResponseHandler(interimFile));
                completableFuture.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
        client.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to use post-call analytics? And how are you sending the request? We're missing some code here if you could share please.

Comment: Yes, we're trying to use post-call analytics. The error is thrown because of this line ``` event.subscribe(c -> System.out.println(c.sdkEventType()));``` . If I remove this then I'm getting ```ChannelClosedException```

Answer (score 0):

As per the example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/using-streaming-api.html, class:EventWriter method:writeConfigurationEvent, in the context of the SubscriptionImpl executor thread, you need to send a ConfigurationEvent using

```
 subscriber.onNext(configurationEvent);
```

before the first invocation of

```
 subscriber.onNext(audioEvent);
```

My solution seems like an awkward workaround, I don't know why it is necessary given that the StartCallAnalyticsStreamTranscriptionRequest can include the ConfigurationEvent that describes the audio stream channel and other settings.   ... AWS Java-SDK bug ?